# rsync 2.6.9 crashing on macOS Monterey

Tags: macos, kernel-panic, rsync, monterey

On Big Sur I had an `rsync` command running daily to backup files from a network drive to an external harddrive. I've recently upgraded to Monterey and now it's crashing the mac, even if I just try a dry run. Any ideas? This command will crash my mac. See stacktrace below.

```
rsync -av --dry-run /Volumes/FranArchives/ /Volumes/FranBackup_6TB/FranArchives/



panic(cpu 1 caller 0xfffffe0015e0acbc): watchdog timeout: no checkins from watchdogd in 94 seconds (53 total checkins since monitoring last enabled)
Debugger message: panic
Memory ID: 0x6
OS release type: User
OS version: 21A559
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 21.1.0: Wed Oct 13 17:33:24 PDT 2021; root:xnu-8019.41.5~1/RELEASE_ARM64_T8101
Fileset Kernelcache UUID: 39AE122AC7508C4798C8CF27369575F7
Kernel UUID: 65055A0F-950D-365E-BE19-6B3D6230C622
iBoot version: iBoot-7429.41.5
secure boot?: YES
Paniclog version: 13
KernelCache slide: 0x000000000daf8000
KernelCache base:  0xfffffe0014afc000
Kernel slide:      0x000000000e31c000
Kernel text base:  0xfffffe0015320000
Kernel text exec slide: 0x000000000e400000
Kernel text exec base:  0xfffffe0015404000
mach_absolute_time: 0x36fde7c34
Epoch Time:        sec       usec
  Boot    : 0x61833553 0x0005736b
  Sleep   : 0x00000000 0x00000000
  Wake    : 0x00000000 0x00000000
  Calendar: 0x618337b5 0x000af6b1

Zone info:
Foreign   : 0xfffffe001c854000 - 0xfffffe001c868000
Native    : 0xfffffe100066c000 - 0xfffffe300066c000
Readonly  : 0 - 0
Metadata  : 0xfffffe68a3418000 - 0xfffffe68af3a8000
Bitmaps   : 0xfffffe68af3a8000 - 0xfffffe68b4fb4000
Largest zones:
Zone Name                      Cur Size  Free Size
kext.   kalloc.32768              5292M         0K
        APFS_INODES                 66M     32447K
        ubc_info zone               17M         9K
        kalloc.type0.32              3M        16K
        APFS_4K_OBJS                 2M       672K
CORE 0 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe001558c640
CORE 1 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe001558af90
CORE 2 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe001558c640
CORE 3 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe001558c640
CORE 4 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe001558c644
CORE 5 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe001558c644
CORE 6 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe001558c644
CORE 7 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe001558c644
CORE 0 PVH locks held: None
CORE 1 PVH locks held: None
CORE 2 PVH locks held: None
CORE 3 PVH locks held: None
CORE 4 PVH locks held: None
CORE 5 PVH locks held: None
CORE 6 PVH locks held: None
CORE 7 PVH locks held: None
CORE 0: PC=0xfffffe0016a590a8, LR=0xfffffe0016a7727c, FP=0xfffffe6096e0bc20
CORE 1 is the one that panicked. Check the full backtrace for details.
CORE 2: PC=0xfffffe001548ab5c, LR=0xfffffe001548ab5c, FP=0xfffffe609ada3ef0
CORE 3: PC=0xfffffe001548ab5c, LR=0xfffffe001548ab5c, FP=0xfffffe609a9f3ef0
CORE 4: PC=0xfffffe001548ab60, LR=0xfffffe001548ab5c, FP=0xfffffe6094c23ef0
CORE 5: PC=0xfffffe001548ab5c, LR=0xfffffe001548ab5c, FP=0xfffffe609a9b3ef0
CORE 6: PC=0xfffffe001548ab60, LR=0xfffffe001548ab5c, FP=0xfffffe6094de3ef0
CORE 7: PC=0xfffffe001548ab5c, LR=0xfffffe001548ab5c, FP=0xfffffe600c8ebef0
Total cpu_usage: 25378940
Thread task pri cpu_usage
0xfffffe150e216db8 kernel_task 95 19381
0xfffffe150df34d10 kernel_task 0 5472552
0xfffffe150e38c7d8 kernel_task 0 5800955
0xfffffe150df387d8 kernel_task 0 8315036
0xfffffe150e4b8688 kernel_task 0 0

Panicked task 0xfffffe150df2c6a8: 0 pages, 484 threads: pid 0: kernel_task
Panicked thread: 0xfffffe150e38c7d8, backtrace: 0xfffffe60573c7800, tid: 449
          lr: 0xfffffe0015456464  fp: 0xfffffe60573c7870
          lr: 0xfffffe0015456134  fp: 0xfffffe60573c78e0
          lr: 0xfffffe0015591c30  fp: 0xfffffe60573c7900
          lr: 0xfffffe0015584e84  fp: 0xfffffe60573c7980
          lr: 0xfffffe001558284c  fp: 0xfffffe60573c7a40
          lr: 0xfffffe001540b7f8  fp: 0xfffffe60573c7a50
          lr: 0xfffffe0015455dac  fp: 0xfffffe60573c7df0
          lr: 0xfffffe0015455dac  fp: 0xfffffe60573c7e60
          lr: 0xfffffe0015c53cc4  fp: 0xfffffe60573c7e80
          lr: 0xfffffe0015e0acbc  fp: 0xfffffe60573c7eb0
          lr: 0xfffffe0015e0a0a4  fp: 0xfffffe60573c7ef0
          lr: 0xfffffe0015e07b18  fp: 0xfffffe60573c7f10
          lr: 0xfffffe00165f0de0  fp: 0xfffffe60573c7fb0
          lr: 0xfffffe0015b9fc8c  fp: 0xfffffe60573c7fc0
          lr: 0xfffffe00155859a8  fp: 0xfffffe60573c7fe0
          lr: 0xfffffe001540b86c  fp: 0xfffffe60573c7ff0
          lr: 0xfffffe001548ab5c  fp: 0xfffffe60114dbef0
          lr: 0xfffffe001548ad74  fp: 0xfffffe60114dbf20
          lr: 0xfffffe0015414e78  fp: 0x0000000000000000
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleInterruptController(1.0d1)[18EE90CF-4C28-3A06-AB27-9CA5CA30D6BA]@0xfffffe00165ee6b0->0xfffffe00165f1df3
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleARMPlatform(1.0.2)[478C7C28-E159-3083-A01D-1BBB61C10D35]@0xfffffe0015dbe260->0xfffffe0015e069fb
         com.apple.driver.AppleARMWatchdogTimer(1.0)[0CEBD185-AF80-3764-BD8B-43C9F0D41208]@0xfffffe0015e06a00->0xfffffe0015e0b18b
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleARMPlatform(1.0.2)[478C7C28-E159-3083-A01D-1BBB61C10D35]@0xfffffe0015dbe260->0xfffffe0015e069fb

last started kext at 1253165174: com.apple.filesystems.smbfs    4.0 (addr 0xfffffe0015305980, size 64483)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 4.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.fileutil  20.036.15
com.apple.driver.AppleALSColorSensor    1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostBillboardDevice    1.0
com.apple.UVCService    1
com.apple.driver.AppleBiometricServices 1
com.apple.driver.CoreKDL    1
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  452.30.4
com.apple.driver.AppleAOPVoiceTrigger   100.1
com.apple.driver.BCMWLANFirmware4378.Hashstore  1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.ReadWriteDiskImage  493.0.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.UDIFDiskImage   493.0.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.RAMBackingStore 493.0.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.FileBackingStore    493.0.0
com.apple.driver.SEPHibernation 1
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    11.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  1933.41.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBDeviceNCM  5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 4.0.3
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.nke.l2tp  1.9
com.apple.filesystems.tmpfs 1
com.apple.filesystems.lifs  1
com.apple.IOTextEncryptionFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  582.40.4
com.apple.security.BootPolicy   1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePMP   1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartIO2  1
com.apple.driver.ApplePMPFirmware   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSPMIPMU   1.0.1
com.apple.AppleEmbeddedSimpleSPINORFlasher  1
com.apple.driver.AppleCS42L83Audio  502.6
com.apple.driver.AppleTAS5770LAmp   502.6
com.apple.driver.AppleT8020SOCTuner 1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103CLPCv3   1
com.apple.driver.AppleEventLogHandler   1
com.apple.AGXG13G   187.57
com.apple.driver.AppleAVD   415
com.apple.driver.AppleAVE2  501.6.9
com.apple.driver.AppleJPEGDriver    4.7.8
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileDispH13G-DCP    140.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleSynopsysUSB40XHCI 1
com.apple.driver.AudioDMAController-T8103   100.51
com.apple.driver.AppleSPIMC 1
com.apple.driver.AppleSerialShim    1
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8960XNCO   1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103PMGR 1
com.apple.driver.AppleS8000AES  1
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8920XPWM   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleS8000DWI  1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleInterruptController   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothModule   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSamsungSerial 1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBCMWLANBusInterfacePCIe   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMCDP29XXUpdateSupport 1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8020DART 1
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8940XI2C   1.0.0d2
com.apple.driver.AppleT8101 1
com.apple.driver.AppleM68Buttons    1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBUserHCI    1
com.apple.iokit.IOKitRegistryCompatibility  1
com.apple.iokit.EndpointSecurity    1
com.apple.driver.AppleDiskImages2   126.40.1
com.apple.AppleSystemPolicy 2.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   402
com.apple.kec.InvalidateHmac    1
com.apple.kec.AppleEncryptedArchive 1
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   228
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   9.0.0
com.apple.driver.driverkit.serial   6.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily 1010.2
com.apple.plugin.IOgPTPPlugin   1000.11
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.1.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleMesaSEPDriver 100.99
com.apple.iokit.IOBiometricFamily   1
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio  412.8
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   300.10
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAOPAudio  102.2
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.KernelBacked    493.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleTrustedAccessory  1
com.apple.iokit.AppleSEPGenericTransfer 1
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPHDCPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleEmbeddedUSBXHCIPCI    1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedUSB   1
com.apple.driver.AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl  1
com.apple.driver.AppleConvergedPCI  1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothDebug    1
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.driver.AppleBTM   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    8.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    8.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltUSBDownAdapter 1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 4.1.1
com.apple.nke.ppp   1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleBSDKextStarter    3
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleDCPDPTXProxy  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.DCPDPFamilyProxy   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSPU   1
com.apple.iokit.IONVMeFamily    2.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleDiagnosticDataAccessReadOnly  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleNANDConfigAccess  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleStockholmControl  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleDialogPMU 1.0.1
com.apple.AGXFirmwareKextG13GRTBuddy    187.57
com.apple.AGXFirmwareKextRTBuddy64  187.57
com.apple.driver.AppleCSEmbeddedAudio   502.6
com.apple.driver.AppleHPM   3.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedAudio 502.6
com.apple.iokit.AppleARMIISAudio    100.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSART  1
com.apple.driver.ApplePassthroughPPM    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCA2-T8103    600.95
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedAudioLibs 100.9.1
com.apple.iokit.IOGPUFamily 35.11
com.apple.driver.AppleH11ANEInterface   5.33.0
com.apple.driver.DCPAVFamilyProxy   1
com.apple.iokit.IOMobileGraphicsFamily-DCP  343.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleDCP   1
com.apple.driver.AppleFirmwareKit   1
com.apple.driver.AppleFirmwareUpdateKext    1
com.apple.iokit.IOMobileGraphicsFamily  343.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSPMI  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103TypeCPhy 1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXDCIARM    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXDCI   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBDeviceFamily   2.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleSynopsysUSBXHCI   1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedUSBHost   1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.driver.ApplePMGR  1
com.apple.driver.AppleARMWatchdogTimer  1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleDisplayCrossbar   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleTypeCPhy  1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    7.2.8
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103PCIeC    1
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 9.3.2
com.apple.driver.ApplePIODMA    1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103PCIe 1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothDebugService 1
com.apple.driver.AppleBCMWLANCore   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2b1
com.apple.driver.IOImageLoader  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOLYHAL    1
com.apple.iokit.IODisplayPortFamily 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGPIOICController  1.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleFireStormErrorHandler 1
com.apple.driver.AppleMultiFunctionManager  1
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedPCIE  1
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileApNonce 1
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    1000.11
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 493.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    593
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    9.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   9.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUARTTransport  9.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  9.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHostControllerPCIeTransport 9.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   9.0.0
com.apple.driver.FairPlayIOKit  68.13.0
com.apple.iokit.CoreAnalyticsFamily 1
com.apple.iokit.CSRBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport  9.0.0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 9.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPKeyStore   2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    532.40.7
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  209.40.6
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   452.30.4
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   452.30.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIPAppender    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.RTBuddy    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedTempSensor    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleARMPMU    1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAccessoryManager  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOnboardSerial 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSkywalkFamily 1.0
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleA7IOP 1.0.2
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.driver.AppleBiometricSensor   2
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.AUC   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAVFamily  1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHDCPFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOCECFamily 1
com.apple.iokit.IOAudio2Family  1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIISController 100.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAudioClockLibs    100.9.1
com.apple.driver.AppleM2ScalerCSCDriver 265.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   302.9
com.apple.driver.IODARTFamily   1
com.apple.security.quarantine   4
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.security.AppleImage4  4.1.0
com.apple.kext.CoreTrust    1
com.apple.iokit.IOCryptoAcceleratorFamily   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleARMPlatform   1.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  47
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    12.0



** Stackshot Succeeded ** Bytes Traced 44552 (Uncompressed 159088) **
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to update rsync.

Here is a link on how to use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) to update rsync.

https://dev.to/al5ina5/updating-rsync-on-macos-so-you-re-not-stuck-with-14-year-old-software-1b5i

Comment: weird thing is I was originally trying to use the latest rsync on Big Sur but that was crashing and the only thing that worked was using the old rsync that comes with mac os by default. I tried the latest rsync via homebrew with Monterey and still crashes.

Comment: OK so what are the formats of FranArchives and FranBackup_6TB? Are they APFS, HFS or what? Maybe it's unable to handle that format?

Comment: FranBackup_6TB is APFS, connected directly to my mac via usb. FranArchives is a network drive being shared out as SMB/CIFS. The goal is to make daily backups of FranArchives to Franbackup_6TB.

Comment: ended up giving up on using my mac to do the backups.. moved over to a windows machine and I'm using robocopy.