# Kernel Panic - RSYNC 3.2.7 - While backing up to (SMB) Network Drive/NAS

Tags: backup, crash, nas, rsync

Kernel Panic / Crash using rsync 3.2.7
I am trying to do this with Launch Control but it also crashes when I run this script from Terminal:

```
#!/bin/zsh
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rsync/3.2.7_1/bin/rsync -rlpt --exclude='.DocumentRevisions-V100' --exclude='.Spotlight-V100' --exclude='.TemporaryItems' --exclude='.Trashes' /Volumes/SAM_500 /Volumes/WORK_BAK 2>&1 | tee /tmp/backup.log
```

I saw this post from a while back that confirms this problem with older versions of rsync such as 2.6.9 which(unbelievably)ships with Ventura.
[rsync 2.6.9 crashing on macOS Monterey](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/430184/rsync-2-6-9-crashing-on-macos-monterey)

rsync 2.6.9 would cause a crash even when backing up between two USB drives.
rsync 3.2.7 fixes *that* issue but, it crashes when I try to back up a USB drive to a (SMB) network/NAS drive. I can provide the crash log if that would be helpful.

My system is a 2023 MacBook pro running Ventura 13.4.1

My NAS is one I built using Truenas Scale.

Comment: I’m having the same exact problem. I tried with a few types of external drives (spinny disks and nvme). My system is an m1 macbook air running 13.4.1

Comment: There is an ever newer (pre-release?)version of rsync at https://rsync.samba.org/ 3.3.0. I tried to install it manually because it is not available from homebrew, but I could not get it to install/work. However, I'm kind of a newb, so perhaps what I downloaded from samba.org isn't meant for Mac OS.

Comment: Ditto the exact same problem. Ventura changed some of the AFP tech and it's now deprecated as a connection protocol with my Synology NAS. Disabled AFP; enabled SMB; reconnected and… blammo. PANIC somewhere early in a large rsync session.